# Pointers with arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Code 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int* arr[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *arr[i] = i;
    }
    printf("%d",arr[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
13509232
```

Code 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int* arr[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *arr[i] = i;
    }
    printf("%d",arr[3][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

I've declared an array of pointers.  Instead of going for *arr[3] to dereference the value stored, I can simply write arr[3][0] to dereference it. It works for all dimensions of arrays.  Just by adding an extra zero to it's dimension, dereferences it's value stored at the location.

I couldn't get it, because at the very first place, arr[3] is 1D array and arr[3][0] is 2D array.  After all, arr[3] is an address, and arr[3][0] is a value stored at the address arr[3].  Can I use in this way to get rid of * operator?  Kindly explain in simple terms.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Let's take the simplest case, single variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int k=5;
    int *ptr=&k;
    printf("%d",ptr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. It hides errors if you forget to include stdlib.h (which, incidentally, you did).

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d",arr[3]);`   the value the code is trying to print is an ADDRESS.  not an integer.   So the correct format specifier is '%p' not '%d'

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, alway check (!= NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: If the code is trying to print the value pointed to be the array entries, the correct syntax would be: `printf( "%d\n", *(arr[3]) );`  This takes into account the value you want to access AND consideration of the precedence of the C operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr[x]` can be written as `*(ptr+x)`. So, `ptr[0]` translates to `*(ptr+0)` which is `*ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

`%d` expects the value itself, not a pointer to it. `arr[3]` is a pointer, the 4th pointer in your pointer array. `arr[3][0]` is the actual number. You could also write `*arr[3]`, and you actually do, in the loop.

Pointers behave similar to arrays, after you allocate memory to `int *a`, you can store a value to the pointed location as `*a=123` or as `a[0]=123`. Also if you allocate memory for 2 integers, you can access the second item as `a[1]` (which is simpler), but also as `*(a+1)`

Bottom line: in terms of `int`-s, you have a 2D array, just not a tightly-packed `n*m`-style one, but one often reffered as jagged (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Answer (score 0):

Since the address calculated for both the cases will be same so it it fine to use they arr[3][0].
Let assume address of arr[3] to be 1000.
Son address for arr[3][0] will be 1000+0*sizeof(int) i.e 1000

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy interpretation for using `[0]` to deference(although I won't recommend it). See this small code:

```
int i;
int j[1];
```

What is difference between these 2? obviously one is array with size 1, but if you think about it, array of size 1 is somehow equal to defining that type once.

dereferencing with `*` is somehow equal to accessing with array index. But because the data looks like to an array with 1 element, you access it with `[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this type of code. And try to change you're code to this way,
Hope this might help you.
Cheers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float *p, tot = 0;
    int i, n;

    printf("Number of observations: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    p = (float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));

    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory is not allocated");
        exit(1); 
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", p+i);
    }


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        tot += *(p+i);
    }

    printf("\nAverage = %.2f\n", tot/n);


    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input:**

Number of observations: 4

12.12

34.14

43.1

45.87

**Sample Output:**

Average  = 33.81